# Most user friendly Ubuntu IDE

Tags: php, ide

What is the most user friendly IDE for HTML, CSS and JS on ubuntu? I have heard it said that programming on the Linux platform can be quite potent when creating server applications. Can you good people post your photos or screenshots of workspaces where any IDEs are used heavily. Thanks tons...

Comment: I personally prefer Aptana Studio for web development, many programmers use Vim with plugins for this.

Comment: I agree with tikend. But "most user friendly" is VERY subjetive. Please add in features you consider "Must Have" into your question to narrow down what you consider user friendly.

Comment: `Sublime text` is extremely powerful but simple tool, but it takes times to learn to make it powerful.

Comment: do i get Aptana from the SoftWare centre? OMG, SublimeText on UBUNTU??!

Comment: I cant get the aptana studio from the Ubuntu Software center :(

Comment: Many thanks for getting back to me on this one tikend, @Rinzwind, Web-E. Well I'm essentially looking for a simple, no-frills but very functional IDE for my Dell Inspiron Duo running Ubuntu 13.04 which I now use when travelling- I'm sorely missing NotePad++ for windows.

Comment: if you like notepad++ try gedit (it is a text editor that can use syntax highlight ;) (aptana is 3rd party: you need to download it from their site; gedit is a native text editor ;) )

Comment: I second @Rinzwind. I cannot imagine anything more friendly than `vim`, so there you have it.

Comment: I refuse to post an "answer" here, for your question is opinion based and therefore should be considered off-topic. Nevertheless, now that @January said Jehova (vim) I can't resist: Have a look at Emacs. ;-) Be warned, powerful text editors like vim or emacs have a very steep learning curve (especially if you want to learn the keyboard shortcuts - what cannot be avoided for vim and strongly encouraged for emacs).

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop is the best IDE for Ubuntu, to install mono in bash:

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

or use the ubuntu software center, search for mono, then install it.